# Replacing a smart light switch with a standard one

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, light

I’m trying to replace a lightswitch but there’s some unusual wiring inside the box.

It looks like there are three sets of wires coming into the box.
Black/White, Black/Red/White, and Black/White.

I removed an automatic timer switch from the wall, and can’t seem to get a standard two position switch to work.

The switch next to it has the two black wires from the left and center sets. All of the white wires are connected together in the box.

I’m trying to use the red from the center, and the black from the right box, but it doesn’t seem to be affecting the light at all.

What am I missing here?[image][image]

Comment: we need a picture: wire colors are often arbitrary.

Comment: It’s been added

Comment: Which wires were originally connected to the timer switch?  Did you unhook any wires other than those?   **Did the timer-switch work before?**. As an aside, the way those wires are put on the switch's screws, I trust it is this way only for testing and you will properly J-hook them when the time comes.

Comment: why did you call it a smart switch? did it have internet connectivity?